# How to run a Jenkins job in an available agent

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins master and two agents. However the connectivity to one agent(agentA) is bit shaky and I want to use the other agent(agentB) when the connectivity to the first one is not available.

I am only using the Jenkins web interface and have not used scripts. I am trying to figure out how it can be done using the "Restrict where this project can be run"  option in job's configuration. I tried using agentA|| agentB but when agentA is not available it hangs saying "pending - agentA is offline"

Is it possible to have a configuration to achieve what I need?

I can;t leave it blank because I have other agent (agentC, agentD)  which do not want this job to run in.

I am not an admin of the Jenkins server, hence adding new plugins is not my preferred option but it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [Least Load plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/leastload/),

> By default Jenkins tries to allocate a jobs to the last node is was executed on. This can result in nodes being left idle while other nodes are overloaded.

As you generalized the example, I'm not 100% sure if your situation can be solved by simply better labelling of your nodes or you want to look at least load plugin (it is designed for balancing the load across nodes). Your example appears to show Node names (ie; agentA/agentB). The Queue allocation logic may be "Only A or Only B", then Jenkins sticks to it. Load balancing may not address that as while a Node (a Computer) name  is also a label, it may have additional logic tied to it.

If you label the pair of nodes in a pool with a common label, say "CapabilityA", and constrain your jobs to run where "CapabilityA" rather than the node names, you may find jobs float across the pool (to B if A is not available. That's how we have our nodes labelled - by Capability, and we see jobs floating across nodes, but only once the first node is full (4 executors each), so not balanced.

Nodes can have many labels and you can use [label conditions](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent-parameters) to have [complex constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31369101/598141).